# Is it possible that my laptop shut down because my mobile is too close?

Tags: laptop, mobile-phone, magnet

If I put my phone on my notebook's left corner, it shuts down. Can anybody give me reliable explanation as to why this is happening??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most likely, there is a magnet that tells the notebook when the lid is closed. If your phone or mobile device also has a magnet, it can activate it. I know this first hand with my old Blackberry and my MacBook Pro when I first bought it.

Comment: One reason I always set it to just turn the screen off.

Comment: Speaker coils and vibration motors would typically have (small) magnetic cores. Depending on how sensitive the sensor in the laptop is it could be one of these that is the culprit. Or it could simply be the metal mass of the phone tripping a MEMS magnetometer. In any case the result is the same, something about the phone is tripping a sensor to turn off the laptop.